# Using mask to pick next value in the mask if it doesn't match my if condition check

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

there, I've currently got a little piece of code to determine if a variable which will change often, is in my mask array or not. If it is in the mask, I want to assign that variable to be used later, but if it doesn't, I want it to be able to select the next value in the mask where the condition would be met. Here is my code just now, and the output:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


hyst = pd.DataFrame({"test":[12, 4, 5, 4, 1, 3, 2, 5, 10, 9, 7, 5, 3, 6, 3, 2 ,1, 5, 2]})

possible_overload_cycle = 1
index_pos_overload = np.array([hyst.index[i] for i in range(0, len(hyst)-1, 5)])

if possible_overload_cycle in index_pos_overload:
    hyst_overload_cycle = possible_overload_cycle
else:
    hyst_overload_cycle = index_pos_overload[np.nonzero(index_pos_overload)[0][0]]
print(hyst_overload_cycle)

5
```

This works fine for if the possible_overload_cycle is at anything below 5, but if it were to be say, 7, this is my output:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


hyst = pd.DataFrame({"test":[12, 4, 5, 4, 1, 3, 2, 5, 10, 9, 7, 5, 3, 6, 3, 2 ,1, 5, 2]})

possible_overload_cycle = 7
index_pos_overload = np.array([hyst.index[i] for i in range(0, len(hyst)-1, 5)])

if possible_overload_cycle in index_pos_overload:
    hyst_overload_cycle = possible_overload_cycle
else:
    hyst_overload_cycle = index_pos_overload[np.nonzero(index_pos_overload)[0][0]]
print(hyst_overload_cycle)
5
```

This isn't my desired output, my desired output for this would be:

```
print(hyst_overload_cycle)

10
```

How do I get it to move along to the next value in the mask? I'm using np.nonzero to try this, but I think I need to change the first `[0]` to determine what dimension of the array `possible_overload_cycle` is at. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve it?

```
index_pos_overload[list(index_pos_overload > possible_overload_cycle).index(True)]
```